# Send data to custom dimensions and metrics in google Universal Analytics with ecommerce tracking

Tags: php, google-analytics, universal-analytics

Here is my Universal Analytics code for custom definatons and e-commerce tracking.ecommerce tracking is working fine all the data are fetching in google analytics dashboard but custom dimensions and metrics data is not showing there.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX',XXXXX);
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');   
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
'id': '<?php echo $ordr_id; ?>',             
'affiliation': 'XXXXXX',
'revenue': '<?php echo $amount; ?>',      
'shipping': '<?php echo $shipping_amount; ?>',    
'tax': '0.00',                    
'currency': 'USD'
});



ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
'id': '<?php echo $ordr_id; ?>',                 
'name': '<?php echo $product_name; ?>',          
'sku': '<?php echo $sku; ?>',                 
'category': '<?php echo $category_name; ?>',  
'price': '<?php echo $final_price; ?>',          
'quantity': '<?php echo $quantity; ?>'         
});




ga('send', 'pageview', {
'dimension1': '<?php echo $product_name; ?>',
'metric2': '<?php echo $final_price; ?>',
'metric3': '<?php echo $final_price; ?>'
});


ga('ecommerce:send');
```

any help related to this is greatly appreciated. thnx!!

Comment: Did you create your custom dimensions/metrics in the property settings ? Did you wait for some time (custom values may take a day to show up) ? Unrelated, currency code should be USD (or any other of the supported 3 letter codes https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/currencies).

Comment: @EikePierstorff yes i have created dimensions and metrics. which is also showing in custom report section of google analytics dashboard but with no data in it.

Comment: @EikePierstorff ecommerce code is working fine. is there any problem with custom defination code above?

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem. I don't see the custom dimension data showing up even though I do know that it's getting sent. Any ideas??

Comment: @user2306941 check the below solutions may be it will help..

Comment: @Raj I realized I had to use the enhanced version of the plugin to use product scope for dimension, so once I switched to that it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use ecommerce with custom dimensions and metrics in `analytics.js`, do not set `ga()` function. Because it send CD, CM to google server on two times that is addTransaction and addItem.

So, you can use CD and CM in `ga('ecommerce:addItem', {...})`.

For example,

`

```
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
'id': '<?php echo $ordr_id; ?>',
'name': '<?php echo $product_name; ?>',
'sku': '<?php echo $sku; ?>',
'category': '<?php echo $category_name; ?>',
'price': '<?php echo $final_price; ?>',
'quantity': '<?php echo $quantity; ?>',
'metric1': value,
'dimension1': value
});
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Above Code is working Fine. just a little change in it works for me.

```
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', {
'dimension1': '<?php echo $product_name; ?>',
'metric2': '<?php echo $final_price; ?>',
'metric3': '<?php echo $final_price; ?>'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add dimension and metrics to ecommerce tracking than this might help:

```
...

ga('set', 'dimension1', '<?php echo $product_name; ?>');
ga('set', 'metric2', '<?php echo $final_price; ?>');
ga('set', 'metric3', '<?php echo $final_price; ?>');

ga('ecommerce:send');

ga('send', 'pageview');
```